# Problems with a ring isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $k$ be a field and consider $a=(a_0,\ldots,a_n)\in k^{n+1}$ with $a_0\neq0$. Now $\rho(a)=\left(\{a_iT_j-a_jT_i\;:\; 0\le i<j\le n\}\right)$ is an homogeneous ideal of $k[T_0,\ldots,T_n]$ and I must show that $k[T_0,\ldots,T_n]/\rho(a)$ is isomorphic to $k[T_0]$.

I think that the right homomorphism is $f(T_0,\ldots,T_n)\mapsto f(T_0, \frac{a_1}{a_0}T_0,\ldots,\frac{a_n}{a_0}T_0)$ but I have problems to show that the kernel is $\rho(a)$. How to prove it?

Thanks  in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible approaches:

1) By using repeatedly the division algorithm for univariate polynomials. In this case note that $\rho(a)$ is in fact generated by $a_0T_i-a_iT_0$ with $i=1,\dots, n$ and write $$f(T_0,T_1,\dots,T_n)=(a_0T_1-a_1T_0)g(T_0,T_1,\dots,T_n)+f_1(T_0,T_2,\dots,T_n)$$ and so on.

2) By using the [division algorithm for multivariate polynomials](http://math.rice.edu/~evanmb/math499fall09/vigrenotes5.pdf). In this case one can write $f(T_0,T_1,\dots,T_n)=\sum_{0\le i<j\le n}(a_iT_j-a_jT_i)g_{ij}(T_0,T_1,\dots,T_n)+r(T_0,\dots,T_n)$ and observe that $r\in k$.